# Python Tkinter, widgets often appear different in size and layout (in different machines eg., Linux or windows). Can't this be solved?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have designed a GUI using Pyhton Tkinter. However using geometry managers and after resizing the images, it appears different in different machines. I designed it in windows, and my friend uses kali linux, the wigdets were misplaced and resized.

Comment: Can you please give some code that shows the problem? `tcl` was designed to be the same on all OSs so there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: What does "appears different" mean? That phrase is far too vague. Please provide us a [mcve] and a couple of screenshots to illustrate the problem. Please do not post your entire program. You should be able to create a new program using the same techniques of your real program but with just a very few widgets.

Answer (score 1):

This is how tkinter is designed to work. There's really no way to "solve" the problem since tkinter is working as designed. Different platforms have different defaults for fonts, border widths, screen dimensions, default sizes, and so on.

That being said, the issues with your code can almost certainly be solved. Tkinter excels at creating user interfaces that work well on a variety of platforms and resolutions when used properly. However, because we can't see specifically how your program was designed, we're not going to be able to give specific advice.